# How to create a dropdown which shows textbox on selecting a value

Tags: java, xml, alfresco

I am working on a project where my client requires a feature in alfresco where a dropdown is selected automatically a textbox should be visible below that dropbox.
Can anybody help me with this?
Do i have to create a java class for this?
I am very new to this software.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No you do not have need to create a java class for this you can do it using simply by surf page.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have need to create a java class for this you can do it using simply by surf page to create a surf page refer this link.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-page.html

add your code of dropdown component and a textbox below it as html in .ftl file as explained above documentation link.

or you can do it by using binding share webscript to ftl page

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-page.html

If you wanted to get display your data in this page so you have to bind your webscript component to this page ex.

ftl file.

```
<#include "/org/alfresco/include/alfresco-template.ftl" />
<@templateHeader></@>
<@templateBody>
   <@markup id="alf-hd">
   <div id="alf-hd">
      <@region scope="global" id="share-header" chromeless="true"/>
   </div>
   </@>
   <@markup id="bd">
    <div id="bd">
        <@region scope="template" id="test-id"/>
    </div>
   </@>
</@>
<@templateFooter>
   <@markup id="alf-ft">
   <div id="alf-ft">
      <@region id="footer" scope="global" />
   </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

template-instance file

```
<template-instance>
   <template-type>org/alfresco/<<temp-type>></template-type>
   <components>

      <component>
         <region-id>test-id</region-id>
         <url>/components/test-url</url>
      </component>

   </components>
</template-instance>
```

This tag's ID must be same as your component's id which you have to define in your template-instance files for creating component refer this link

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/surf-object-xml-reference-component.html http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-surf-web-scripts.html

<@region scope="template" id="test-id"/>
refer this link for creation of webscript component

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-surf-web-scripts.html your webscript url must be same as coponent's url

/components/test-url